# How to install aws cli?

Tags: apt, package-management, aws

What is the best way to install the aws cli?

There are a few conflicting resources about this online.

Comment: `sudo apt install awscli` or in a Python virtual environment (will not require `sudo`) `python -m pip install awscli` (https://pypi.org/project/awscli/). Avoids all the hassle with snaps and installer downloads and allows easy update.

Comment: One thing that you need to be aware of is that AWS have released a version 2 of the CLI that has features that may be important to you such as `aws configure sso`. AWS has not released a PyPi package for version 2 and I can't find an `apt` package for version 2. If you are in need of version 2 it looks like the official AWS install method is required. There is a third party PyPi package for version 2 but I had problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be installed with snap

```
sudo snap install aws-cli
```

https://snapcraft.io/aws-cli